# Why does setting the 'QueuingEnabled' of a COM+ app remotely by powershell cause the save to fail?

Tags: powershell, com, msmq, com+, comadmin

I have this powershell script which is creating COM+ applications on a remote machine:

```
$credentials = Get-Credential -Message "Test" -User "DOMAIN\User"
$roleRM = new-pssession -computername MACHINE -credential $credentials

Invoke-Command -Session $roleRM -scriptblock `
{
$comAdmin = New-Object -ComObject ("COMAdmin.COMAdminCatalog.1")   
$comApplicationCollection = $comAdmin.GetCollection("Applications")
$comApplicationCollection.Populate()
$comApplication = $comApplicationCollection.Add()
$comApplication.Value("Name") = "Server"
$comApplication.Value("ApplicationAccessChecksEnabled") = 0
$comApplication.Value("AccessChecksLevel") = (0)
$comApplication.Value("Authentication") = (1)
$comApplication.Value("Identity") = "DOMAIN\User"
$comApplication.Value("Password") = "password"
$comApplication.Value("QueuingEnabled") = 1
$comApplication.Value("QueueListenerEnabled") = 1
$comApplicationCollection.SaveChanges()
}
```

but when I try and run it it fails with this error:

`Exception calling "SaveChanges" with "0" argument(s): "An operations error occurred.
"
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComMethodTargetInvocation
    + PSComputerName        : MACHINE`

If I exclude this line:

```
$comApplication.Value("QueuingEnabled") = 1
```

then it saves and creates the application correctly.  If I run this script locally then it creates the application correctly on the local machine with `QueuingEnabled=1`, but always fails when running on a remote machine.

Why might this be?

Comment: Does it work if you set it to `$true` instead of `1`? `$comApplication.Value("QueuingEnabled") = $true`

Answer (score 0):

Try setting "Authentication" to 4 or 6 and see if that changes anything. See [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686107(v=VS.85).aspx#authentication).